# What is a good Selenium strategy if you don't know if certain elements exist or not?

Tags: java, selenium

I am writing a web spider for a site on the public internet - that is, I can't control the site that is the target. For some reason certain elements I am interested in change their name, id and similar between reloads.

Since Selenium, AFAIK, doesn't have a method that returns true/false if an element exists or not (instead it throws exceptions), **what is a good strategy to handle this situation?**

In pseudo code

if element A exists click A
else if element B exists click B
else if element C exists click C

Currently I have to surround every if with a try/catch.

Does Selenium have something built in for this purpose or should I write my own helper method?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Boolean elementExists(WebDriver driver, String xpath) {
   // this will not throw any exception, if no element is found, the list will be empty
   List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));
   if (elements.size() > 0) {
      return true;
   }
   else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Any locator can be interpreted with xpath.

For id `"foo"` the xpath will be `"//*[@id = 'foo']"`

For name `"foo"` the xpath will be `"//*[@name = 'foo']"`

etc

Comment: Smart! Thank you. I had a strong feeling that there must be a better way than dozens of try/catch.

Comment: Agreed. Always avoid try/catch blocks if possible.